# Saving Image From DataGridViewImage to the Database

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I'm trying to save my images located in my datagrid with ColumnType of "DataGridViewImageColumn" passing thru class and to the class query that I have.

Here's my code.

```
// Class name
 public byte[] Image;

// Getting the value image from datagridview
int i;
for(...){
byte[] image = (byte[])dgv.Rows[i].Cells[7].Value;
MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(image);
belsalesquote.Image = Image.FromStream(ms);
}
```

Error List says *"Cannot Implicitly convert type 'System.Drawing.Image' to 'byte[]'*

My column type inside my database is equal to 'image'.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cant direct convert image to byte

```
  //byte[] image = (byte[])dgv.Rows[i].Cells[7].Value;

  Image image = (Image)dgv.Rows[i].Cells[7].Value;

  using (MemoryStream m = new MemoryStream())
  {
        image.Save(m, image.RawFormat);
        byte[] imageBytes = m.ToArray();

        // Convert byte[] to Base64 String
        string base64String = Convert.ToBase64String(imageBytes);
  }
```

So you can save [base64String] to your db

Comment: what do you mean in [base64String]. I will change my column type from image to [base64String] is that what you mean? :)

Comment: string base64String = Convert.ToBase64String(imageBytes);

its a variable, you can name it anything

so you can store in any NVARCHAR type in database